# perl pdftk functionality not working , getting error

Tags: perl

I was testing the functionality of [`PDF::Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Tk) by installing in cpan module and installed the pdftk binary file and the path to variable and tried running source code.

source code:

```
use PDF::Tk;
my $doc = PDF::Tk->new( pdftk => '/apps/free/pdftk/' );
$doc->call_pdftk( 'input.pdf', 'outPDF.pdf', 'cat', '1-14' );
```

getting error as below:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1-14 releasenote.pdf failed: -1 at
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/PDF/Tk.pm line 73.
```

please guide me in resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are passing the wrong argument to the constructor of PDF::Tk. Have a look [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Tk#new).

You're supposed to pass a hash, with the key `pdftk`, and this should be the path of the executable, not a directory. As you can see [here](https://metacpan.org/source/MRAMBERG/PDF-Tk-0.02/lib/PDF/Tk.pm#L73), this will be executed via `system`, so of course, executing a directory does not work.

To clarify, you should be using:

```
my $doc=PDF::Tk->new(pdftk => '/path/to/pdftk/executable');
```

If your pdftk executable is `/usr/bin/pdftk`, then you do not have to pass it at all as this is the default.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, as the documentation has a typo in it, the parameter is 'pdftk'.  See:
https://github.com/gitpan/PDF-Tk/blob/master/lib/PDF/Tk.pm
line 17.

Comment: Yes, I edited that out after reading the source deeper. The problem is that he's giving a directory instead of the executable.

Comment: Agreed, incorrect path.
Error code -1 = failed to execute system call.
perldoc -f system 
then just search for '-1'

Comment: Thanks all, changed the pdftk executable file path and now the function is working.

Answer (score 0):

for testing the encryption function (by default 128 bit encryption) , i created a pdf file 'apps.pdf' with password protected 'abcd' as password.

source code 1:

```
use PDF::Tk; 
my $doc=PDF::Tk->new(pdftk=>'/apps/free/pdftk/1.44/bin/pdftk');
$doc->call_pdftk('apps.pdf', '1.128.pdf', 'owner_pw', 'abcd');
```

getting error:

```
Error: Unexpected command-line data:
    owner_pw 
where we were expecting an input PDF filename, 
operation (e.g. "cat") or "input_pw". Exiting. 
Errors encountered. No output created. 
Done. Input errors, so no output created. 
pdftk apps.pdf owner_pw abcd 1.128.pdf failed: 256 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/PDF/Tk.pm         line 73.
```

note: created a new pdf 'apps.pdf' with Document Open Password as 'abcd' and permission Password as 'abcd123'.
Please let me know how to resolve it.